# Develop UWP app from a sample code

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I want to develop a new UWP app (to publish to the Windows Store) and found a sample code from Microsoft (available on GitHub) where it makes it much easier for me to implement some parts of my application.
Can I develop my application from the Project of this code sample provided by Microsoft and then add what I want or do I have to create a new project and copy the code that interests me (almost everything) from the Microsoft sample to my project?

Comment: Do you have a link to the sample? What is the license on the sample?

Comment: You should copy into a new project so that your project gets a new GUID and app ID. (I'm assuming the code is under a suitable license.)

Comment: @RaymondChen is correct

Comment: You might want to take a look at windows template studio https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/05/16/announcing-windows-template-studio/

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-coloringbook)

Comment: @RaymondChen is there any way to copy the whole code at once?

Comment: Note that the images in the project are for testing only; [you are not granted the rights to put them in your final app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-coloringbook/blob/master/IMAGE%20LICENSE). You can create a blank project and then just drag the code files into your project from Windows Explorer. Copying the, `.cs`, `.xaml`, and `.xaml.cs` files should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to reuse **parts** of the code, but you should not take the solution as is and just add something to it, because it contains copyright info and identification information of the UWP app project. By far the best option is to create a blank UWP app and build it up using the **code snippets** from the samples you are interested in.

Copying the whole code at once is definitely something I would not recommend and I don't see a reason for that. Most sample apps in the library are just boilerplate shared "sample" UI with the interesting code parts quite distinctly separated into special pages, so if you need some specific functionality, there is a **single file** where you can find it and there is no reason to copy the whole project.